# Fetch results in group based on the occurrence

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, I have a single MySQL table with the name 'car' and 3 columns.

```
+----+--------+------------+
| ID | car_id  | engine |
+----+--------+------------+
| 1  |  123     | on        |
| 2  | 123      | on        |
| 3  | 123      | off       |
| 4  | 123      | on        |
| 5  | 123      | on        |
| 6  | 123      | on        |
| 7  | 123      | off       |
| 8  | 123      | on        |
| 9  | 123      | off       |
+----+--------+------------+
```

Now I want to show the trips this car did. The trips would be determined based on car engine start and stop. For example from the above example we can see that user has made 3 trips as total(From on to off). Now What I want is that if there is a query which gives me only 3 results from on to off meaning if somehow the query groups the records by considering a starting point **on** and ending point **off**. Is it possible in mysql? or the other way around is doing it manually by fetching all the records and working in arrays?

At the moment I am fetching all the records and doing it manually by looping all the data and doing accordingly But this process is slow.

Comment: *"At the moment I am fetching all the records and doing it manually by looping all the data and doing accordingly"* And what is wrong with this way? That is, if it works then what prompted you to ask your question?

Comment: It is slow actually

Comment: @coderdeveloperprogrammer that is strange, do you have many cars in the table?

Comment: If your sample table data is accurate, and follows a "time" order, I'm struggling to see how the driver turned on their car multiple times in a row. Perhaps you need another column on the "time" that on/off occurred? ... You could then sort by "time" and count the sequence changes of "on/off" to know the amount of "trips".

Comment: @nicael yes the table has more then million record

Comment: Have you considered indexing it?

Comment: @GetSet yes the table does have a datetime column in it. But I didn't understand your logic. could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @nicael Yes Already indexed. I have indexed car_id and created. query is fast but if I fetch all the record and then open an array and try to  do looping and manually create an array and passing to mobile app, the final result become slow

Comment: Well herein lies the problem. You give sample data that is not reflective of your actual data. Now, if this were a quick answer, comments could suffice: but you also show **zero** code. So it becomes like fishing in the dark. You can improve your question by including accurate data samples and also, and this is important, actual code.

Comment: could you maybe include your php code that works currently?

Comment: @nicael on face value the OP's question is relatively easy to answer. But this "stinginess" on code idea the OP has decided is quite weird. 27 minutes ago his or her problem would have been solved by simply a question that followed SO rules. ... And now to learn the "sample table" is not even the table the OP is using. Boggles the mind.

Comment: okay hangon. I am attaching more details

Comment: Update the question. Add desired output for this data and precise MySQL version info.

Comment: You need to share the table schema as well.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  (8.0 has more techniques.)

Comment: Please augment the data to intersperse data for another car.  (And thereby invalidate one of the Answers.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it ?

```sql
SELECT * from cars WHERE `engine` = 'off' AND id IN(SELECT id+1 FROM `cars` WHERE `engine` = 'on')
```

Comment: This works with the given data, but what if a different car were at "id+1"??